# How do websites with no content rank so high?

Tags: seo, blackhat

I was just searching for, how to close a sim and I got the website (shown below) on the first page of Google. The website does not have the solution to the problem. there is just a line written about it but the SEO or a trick is played so well that it has got so many real comments. The comments are users asking him to help me close their sims. Now I don't get this. There is no content then how does the site rank so high?

URL: `boltaconsumer.com/complaints/zong-sim-block`

[image: serps]

Comment: Hi, I just noticed my answer is getting a lot of attention and is more popular than the one you've selected. Would you like to update the selected answer?

Comment: @Anagio: Your answer deserved it. Just marked it. Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is plenty of content on that page. I'm sure there are also many pages on boltaconsumer.com which link to it boosting it's internal links all being mostly relevant. It may or may not have external back links, but when I search `zong sim blocked` or related searches there are very few sites with those phrases on them.

Comment: That site is using some trick that is showing a users problem. I think they are taking rss from a complaint center. But, there isn't any relevant solution present on the website. I disagree, have a look again. Its just a problem mentioned on the page(or I should say just a complain.)

Comment: It's not a trick. They have a legitimate blog post which is content, the comments are content. Regardless of how they posted it from an RSS feed, automatic scraper, or manually posted it. It's there and on their site with a lot of comments. It does not matter if there is a solution to the problem. There are many instances of the phrase "Zong sim" and that alone makes the page relevant for various searches with that phrase

Comment: @Akito: I think you overestimate Google's intelligence. Google uses keyword presence to determine relevance, but it doesn't have the intelligence to: 1.) intuit your question from a 3 word search term; 2.) determine if a page actually has the answer to a question; 3.) determine what part of a page is the original post and which parts are guest comments. Anyway, I wish I could vote up this answer twice as Anagio has hit the nail on the head.

Comment: +1 for this. Also I realize Zong is a China/Pakistan venture but OP also got a localized search result for Karachi, Pakistan as clearly seen in the screenshot's results side bar. This effects things greatly and in no way are those results global. Secondly the ranked site is clearly a forum for people to raise complaints and discuss topics. In other words it is very social and has lots of linkbacks and link juice.

Answer (score 5):

If you feel that a website is ranked well due to heavy spam so you can use following Google tool:

https://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/spamreport?hl=en

http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/request.py?contact_type=rich_snippets_spam

But, don't be negative to rank well with your target keywords. There are too many factors to rank well in Google. We can't assume in a second. But, quality always matters. We can notify Google of any spam website.

Answer (score 4):

***I think the king here is the URL***

```
http://www.boltaconsumer.com/complaints/zong-sim-block#comments11
```

That directly contains the word

Zong
Sim
Block

- the reputation of the site `http://www.boltaconsumer.com` is probably good with Google. Genuine traffic across different parts of the country, no spams, the word complaints in URL may also contribute to its high ratings. But I believe it is the URL that is doing the trick.

I saw that it wasn't the only link that was pulled from this site. There were others too which contain sim-block in the URL. That again shows this site has good ratings with Google and the URL does the rest of the trick, although there is nothing in that URL. Hmm there is  one thing, the URL contains the exact same problem that you have and it landed you in perfect spot!

*Experiment*

Now lets say you find solution to this problem and start a blog about it. The chances are your solution will not appear anywhere near the top because your site probably does not have the reputation.